# Create HTML form from JsonData and make it editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have set of key-value in JSON format.

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 23,
  "address": "Lorem ipsum"
  ...
  ...
}
```

I need to create an editable form from this. The main challenge is that I have 100's of such key-value pairs in JSON format. The requirement is to resubmit the form using GET request. Only the fields that have been edited by user has to be submitted.

e.g. if an user makes an edit to "name" = "pete" and age = 24, I need to create a request with http://www.example.com/name=pete&age=24

Since the number of key-value pairs is very large, I cannot submit all the key-values to server every time an user edits some value.

Comment: Hi, can you give an example which explains your reqiurement clearly

Comment: how and where do the old values come from? what did you try so far, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries to do that. Also a simple way to get it, you can be:

```js
function paramsToJSON(){
 var search = location.search.substring(1), json_get;
 try{
  json_get = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(search).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}')
 }catch(e){}

 return json_get || {};
}

var myJSON = {"name": "John", "age": 23, "address": "Lorem ipsum"};
var json = $.extend(myJSON, paramsToJSON()), changes = {};

$(document).ready(function(){

 for(var key in json){
  var element = $("<input>", {type: "text", name: key, value: json[key]});
  var label = $("<label>").append(key).append(element);

  element.bind("keyup change", function(){
   changes[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
  });

  $("#fields").append(label)
 }

 $("#myForm").submit(function(e){
  for(var x in json){
   if(!changes.hasOwnProperty(x) || changes[x] == json[x]){
    $("input[name='"+x+"']").prop("disabled", true)
   }
  }
 });
})
```

```css
label {display:block; text-transform: capitalize;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm"></form><form id="myForm" method="get">
 <div id="fields"></div>
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: The main challenge I am facing is to resubmit the form with only those values that are edited by user. For e.g if "name" is edited, we do no resubmit all the fields, we just send "name" as get parameter to server. Somehow , the values that are edited needs some sort of tracking.

Comment: No php. All this has to be client side only.

Comment: @nirmeshkhandelwal to avoid sending the values of some fields, you must disable the form elements. I updated the demo, check it out. Try on local

Answer (score 0):

```
buildForm = function(formJSON) {
   for(var key in json) {
      $("#myForm").append("<label name='"+key+"' >"+key+"</label>");
      $("#myForm").append("<input type='text' name='"+key+"' value='"+value+"' >");
    }
}

// if your json like this
var json = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 23,
  "address": "NY"
};
buildForm(json);
```